# How to debug: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I just upgraded an MVC project from .NET 4.0 to 4.5 and I'm getting some errors when trying to build.

I have no idea where to start debugging this, so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Or a solution, of course.

> Multiple assemblies
>   with equivalent identity have been imported:
>   'C:[PATH]\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.IO.dll' and
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.IO.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references. [projectname]
>   C:[PATH][PROJECTNAME]\CSC
>
> Multiple assemblies
>   with equivalent identity have been imported:
>   'C:[PATH]\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.Runtime.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references. [projectname]
>   C:[PATH][PROJECTNAME]\CSC
>
> Multiple assemblies
>   with equivalent identity have been imported:
>   'C:[PATH]\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10\lib\net40\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references. [projectname]
>   C:[PATH][PROJECTNAME]\CSC

**What I've Tried**

When I googled the error, this often seemed to be mentioned in relation to EF, so I tried uniinstalling that, and undating to the latest version, but this didn't have any noticable effect.

I also tried updating a bunch of nuget packages to the latest versions, but again, this didn't seem to have any noticable effect.

I have also tried uninstalling Microsoft.Bcl, but it won't let me because:

> Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10' because
>   'Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29' depends on it.

Finally, it seems related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728898/asp-net-web-forms-system-runtime-equivalent-identity-error-in-vs-2015-on-windo), but there is no answer there, and TBH even the question is slightly over my head!

**Update**

I read [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/99989/#Comment_99989) (recommended uninstalling and reinstalling Bcl packages).

I unistalled `Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29` and the bcl packages.  The project built, but when running it locally I got:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

So I reinstalled them. But now I'm still getting the same error message!

I installed `System-Web-Helpers.dll` to no effect.

Comment: You may need to add a [binding redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx) in your web.config for `System.Web.Helpers`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling for a day with this problem.
Reinstalling the bcl nuget package did not help i got the same error

The solution was to unload the project open the csproj file and remove the references by hand (remove all three packages):

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.14-rc\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

You also need to reinstall them. This step is only if the build doesen't work after package reinstallation